# Making a simple rails website but can not make a submit button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie and I am trying to make a very simple website by Rails and I am trying to upload video by making a submit button. At first, I am trying to copy Wistia embed link and paste it into file show.html.erb, and I can show that video. But my problem is, I want to make a submit button and I can submit a new video, no need to copy paste any link from Wistia into file show.html.erb.

Here is my code at show.html.erb if you need

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12 m6">
  <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
    <div class="card-image">
    <script src="//fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/j38ihh83m5.jsonp" async></script>
    <script src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
    <div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_j38ihh83m5" style="height:349px;width:"100%">&nbsp;</div>  
    </div>
    <div class="card-content white-text">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col m4 center">
       <%= image_tag ("courses/1.png"), class: "img-responsive"%> 
       </div> 
       <div class="col m8">
      <span class="card-title"><%= @course.title %></span>
      <p><%= @course.description %></p>   
     </div> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Share code!

Comment: follow this rails guide about active storage https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html

Comment: There is no form nor submit button on your code, start reading here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

you should [create a form](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form) (the `submit` button is included) and [learn about Active Storage](https://www.formakod.fr/tutoriels/developpement/ruby-on-rails/uploader-des-fichiers-avec-active-storage-pour-rails-5-2)